# Not enough '\' characters in service

Tags: smbclient

Gleaning from the [Arch Linux Wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba), I have what I think is the minimal setup of accessing a Windows shared drive via SMB from my Arch Linux 4.20.6:

- `sudo pacman -S samba`
- `sudo echo "logging = systemd" >> /etc/samba/smb.conf` since the `smb` service needs this config file, otherwise it'll crash with the error:

  ```
  Job for smb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
  See "systemctl status smb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
  ```
- `sudo systemctl start smb`

Assuming that the remote Windows machine is at `172.16.17.52`, I'm able to list the share names with

```
smbclient -L 172.16.17.52 -U MyUserName%MyPassword -W OurWindowsDomain
```

Among those is a service of type "Disk" with share name `OurRemoteDirectory` that I'd like to access, i.e., transfer files from and to it.

Hoping to be able to access `OurRemoteDirectory` on the shared drive, I issued

```
smbclient 172.16.17.52/OurRemoteDirectory -U MyUserName%MyPassword -W OurWindowsDomain
```

But that produced this error message:

```
Unable to initialize messaging context

172.16.17.52: Not enough '\' characters in service
```

How can I fix this error and access `OurRemoteDirectory` on the shared drive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix this, simply add two *forward* slashes before the IP address:

```
smbclient //172.16.17.52/OurRemoteDirectory -U MyUserName%MyPassword -W OurWindowsDomain
```

What threw me off was the error message suggesting I should add *backward* slashes and the fact that listing share names with `smbclient -L` does not require any slashes in front of the IP address.

Now I have a command line interface for accessing the remote file system:

> smb: >

Having established the connection, [`man smbclient`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html) describes commands for transferring files, such as `put` and `get`.

---

As a postscript, since v7.40 [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) supports the [smb](/questions/tagged/smb) protocol as well, which makes the `samba` package including `smbclient` superfluous in cases where you only want to transfer files from and to the shared drive:

```bsh
# Upload local file to shared drive
curl --upload-file /home/me/local_file.txt --user "OurWindowsDomain/MyUserName:MyPassword" smb://172.16.17.52/OurRemoteDirectory/Path/To/Dir/
# Download file from shared drive
curl -o file_from_server.txt --user "OurWindowsDomain/MyUserName:MyPassword" smb://172.16.17.52/OurRemoteDirectory/Path/To/Dir/remote_file.txt
```

Currently, `curl` does not support creating remote directories, meaning `Path/To/Dir/` has to exist already. The feature is briefly discussed [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/609).

Comment: `smbclient` understands backslashes too, but because Unix-style shells will parse them as escape characters, you need to inconveniently double them: `smbclient \\\\172.16.17.52\\OurRemoteDirectory -U MyUserName...`

Comment: @telcoM, or use single-quotes (in shells other than `fish`): `smbclient '\\172.16.17.52\OurRemoteDirectory'` (BTW, the `rc` shell doesn't treat backslash as a quoting character).

Comment: Single-quotes don't allow variable expansion inside them, so they can be inconvenient if you need to use `smbclient` in a script to a target specified by a variable. Other than that, they are indeed a valid alternative.